# Change elements in div tag in html through javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, addition

What's the best way to adjust a data offset value within an HTML tag through JavaScript.

Example

```
<div class="box" data-offset="2s"></div>
```

I want to be able to change the value inside the data-offset attribute given a certain browser width.

So that let's say we have a browser width of `400px`, the `data-offset` changes from `2s` to `1s` or so forth.

Comment: Please explain the algorithm that outputs the desired value, given a browser width.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you want, and how, exactly, the attribute value should change based on the width of the browser viewport?

Comment: What exactly do you want and what have you tired? Show us your JavaScript code you’re trying to debug and describe how the algorithm to get the value of `data-offset` based on viewport width works.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your script,

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).resize(function() {
      if(window.width == 400)
         $(".box").attr("data-offset","1s");
   });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: but i guess the OP wants the offset to be 2s